# Android Application - Connecting to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, android, sql, google-app-engine

I've spent 2 days (about 30 hours to find this answer, read all related posts on here and tried everything).

I can't find any SPECIFIC answers relating to android apps and this problem.

I have made an Instance of my Google Cloud SQL, connected to it using MySQL, created my database tables and updated the Cloud SQL.

Built a basic app to test connectivity and insert data into one of the tables.

Problem I am having is:
Generating Cloud SQL specific Endpoints.

I generated backend Endpoints using Eclipse.

I right clicked on my AppEngine Settings:
My Application ID is in there (set all permissions and enabled Google Cloud SQL)

Clicked on Enable Google Cloud SQL --> Use Google Cloud SQL Instance

Here is where I think the problem is: It always fails.
Put my Instance Name: Soemthing:Something
Put my Data BaseName: playerNames
Put my Database Username as root
Put my Database Password to blank

Get this error: 
Creating SQL Model Connection to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).
Details: Error creating SQL Modem Connection connection to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).
(Error:null)
java.lang.NullPointerException

Could Not connect to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance). (Error: null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
OK

Repeated same process but with a password I set for root:

Could not connect to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance). 
(Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Error creating Google Cloud SQL Connection factory connection to Profile (MyTestApp-AppEngine.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).

(Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am pretty sure that I won't be able to even use any of the code unless I get this portion working.  It doesn't generate any Endpoints for Google Cloud SQL - only for Messaging and Device Info

Comment: In practice, you won't be able to access a Cloud SQL instance from Android. For that, you'd need to whitelist the IP of the Android devices connecting to the Cloud SQL instance, and only then, to connect through user/pass.

Answer (score 1):

Your Eclipse must have the Data Tools Platform (DTP) plugin installed, per https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-database.  Some Eclipse installation packages include this (Java EE) and some don't (RCP/RAP).  DTP install info is here:  http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php.

Once you install this plugin, NPE errors should go away.  Switch to Perspective Database Developer and you should be able to connect and drill down into your Cloud SQL tables.